# dowloading cassandra 4.0.9 on windows

Tags: windows, cassandra

I am trying to install cassandra 4.0.9 on windows.

Is there any way to install Cassandra 4.0.9 on Windows? I understood that Windows doe's not support versions 4.0+ of Cassandra.
I need Casandra for a project of mine and I am working on Windows, I can't download an older version because I am working with Spark and it needs Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

> I am working with Spark and it needs Java 11.

I recommend looking at something like [JEnv](https://github.com/FelixSelter/JEnv-for-Windows), which allows you manage and set different JREs on a per-directory basis.  This way, you could run Spark on Java 11 and Cassandra 3.x on Java 8.

> Is there any way to install Cassandra 4.0.9 on Windows?

Is addition to Docker, there is also Minikube.  Running on Minikube is useful if you need to run multiple nodes or if your target production env runs on Kubernetes.  I have a Git repo with scripts and configs to run Cassandra 3 or 4 on Minikube, which can be found here: https://github.com/aploetz/CassandraOnWindows

Answer (score 1):

You can use Docker to run Cassandra 4.x on Windows, and it's recommended way of it.